# PHP MYSQLI SELECT multiple values

Tags: php, select, mysqli

Trying to make a website that uses php and mysqli. I'm trying to have a page select values from a database. For example it would select the site name, site heading, and maybe contact info from the database. I have everything on a .php file now but want to move it to a database so I can make changes from one page on an admin panel. Here is some info I'm using now. I think Wordpress does kinda the same thing just not 100% how to make it work well.

```
table = web_opt

columns = opt_name, opt_value, opt_easy_name
```

For example, I would have an entry as `opt_name = NAME_LONG, opt_value = Example Business Co., opt_easy_name = Business Name`

On the web page I would do something like `<?php echo ['opt_value'] WHERE opt_name = NAME_LONG; ?>`

On the page I would just change the opt_name portion. I know this code is not correct but any thoughts on how I can access something like this? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to take a look at something like [phpMyAdmin](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/intro.html) for creating the database and tables you need - most hosts provide you with a MySQL frontend or can install one - though you can, of course, do this directly with PHP too but you will undoubtedly find it easier with a GUI.

Once you have some sort of schema setup you will then need to look into PHP's [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [MySQL PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) for handling your data and make use of the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tutorial.html).